# generate multiple pdfs from a database

Tags: excel, pdf, adobe, relational-database, acrobat

I would like to generate multiple pdfs at once. Those pdfs should pull data from a database. It can be an excel table or a relational database, doesn't matter, I can create whatever.

Using excel and javascript in adobe acrobat pro I managed to pull data into a template pdf, but for every record (row) I have in excel table I have to manually generate one pdf, then another, and so on.. and there are a lot of records, so I would like to do that automatically if possible.

Is there a way to do that? Any suggestions?

I added an image to better explain it...
[image: example]

Comment: Did you look at the examples [Using forms for reporting](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/form-examples/using-forms-reporting) We use [state.pdf](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext/sandbox/raw/master/resources/pdfs/state.pdf) as template, fill it with the data in [united_states.csv](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext/sandbox/raw/master/resources/data/united_states.csv), resulting in [united_states_2.pdf](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext/sandbox/raw/master/cmpfiles/acroforms/reporting/cmp_united_states_2.pdf). Obviously, you'll need to write some code to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Look into the Acrobat SDK, Section: "Interapplication Communication" to learn how you can control Acrobat via VB/VBA and how you can work with the JavaScript Object (JSO).

Then have a look into the "Acrobat JavaScript Scripting reference" and look at 
the Doc Object with commands like .. addField and at 
the Field object to set the properties of the fields.

That should do what you want, Reinhard

PS: With Open Office you can save spreadsheets as PDF and with newer version of Excel too. Wouldn't that be already enough or perhaps a mix of above and this.

Answer (score 0):

*Full disclosure: I founded and run Epsillion Software.*

mirta, one option is [Epsillion Publisher](https://www.epsillion.com/). We built it for your exact use case.

You would need to specify what your template should look like. The Epsillion team will design it for you.

You then specify what your variables are in a Word document (e.g., name, last name, date of birth). The software will process the Word and Excel files and return PDFs for you.

Templates are flexible and flow as needed.

Hope that helps. Good luck!